# Cross Compile Error Using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

Tags: archlinux, c, cross-compilation, pi-zero

I am trying to cross compile a C binary from Ubuntu Trusty Tahr x64 to Arch Linux ARM on my Raspberry Pi Zero.

Here is my hello-world.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the example using `make` and successfully executed it in Ubuntu.

Then I installed `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` and used it to compile my example. When I execute the binary on Arch Linux however, I receive a Segmentation Fault.

What went wrong?

Comment: A segmentation fault means that the executable attempted to access memory outside its own address space.  Unfortunately, that by itself tells us nothing.  To further qualify the issue, we'd have to know where in the code the attempt to access memory happened.  Given that this might be a challenging issue ... I'd suggest creating a detailed write-up of the story as a PDF that can be posted ... including screen shots, commands run, source of tools etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-compiled your code, and did not run into a Segmentation Fault.
Here is what my setup looks like - maybe it helps you getting yours to run.
For Cross-Compilation from my Ubuntu 64-bit to my Raspberry Pi B+ (which has the same architecture like the Pi-Zero (ARMv6)) I used the [raspberry tools](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools).

I usually use CodeBlocks to do the compilation for me. But for you, I tried it with a makefile which looks like:

```
 hello-world :  hello-world.c
    /PATH_TO_THE_RPI_TOOLS/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o  hello-world  hello-world.c
```

After running `make`, I copyed the executable to the pi, changed the permissions to `-rwxr--r--` and run the program with:

```
./hello-world
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was using the Ubuntu packages. I'm not sure why they weren't working, but the official raspberry tools do work.